# How to access the values of a TempTable from outside the scope of a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I am trying to call a stored procedure A from another stored procedure B. Stored procedure A will insert records into a #TempTable_A. How can I access the results of #TempTable_A from stored procedure B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the  Proc B is called with in proc A, then it will have access to the temp table..Below is an example

**Proc B defintion**

```
create proc B
as
Begin
select * from #test
End
```

**Proc A definition**

```
 Create proc A
    as begin

    insert into #test
    select * from sometable

    exec B
    end
```